# App crashes at reloadData() for Collectionview with a background fetch

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, background-fetch

So I am doing a background fetch, and after I want to update the UI. The background fetching itself (database) works, but when I want to update the UI, I get a crash `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
According to my xCode `self.newestPublicationsCollectionView.reloadData()` is where the crash occurs in the updateCollections() function.

```
 func updateCollections() {
        // get latest data from Database
        latestPublications = getNewestPublications()

        self.newestPublicationsCollectionView.reloadData()

        self.newestPublicationsCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

       // fix wrong content height
       self.newestPublicationsCollectionViewHeight.constant = self.newestPublicationsCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize().height  
    }
```

Other code in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let fetchViewController = PublicationOverviewController()
                fetchViewController.fetch {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    fetchViewController.updateCollections()
                    }
                    completionHandler(.NewData)
                }
}
```

The .fetch in my PublicationOverviewController

```
func fetch(completion: () -> Void) {
    PublicationFetcher.shared.fetchAllPublications()
    completion()
}
```

I thought the crash was because I needed the UI on the main thread, but that didn't help. Any input would be nice.

**DETAILS:**

In my PublicationFetcher.shared.fetchAllPublications() I do the following:

- get data from backend
- `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RELOAD_NOTIFICATION", object: nil) }`

and under that Reload Notification I do a `updateCollections()`

### **Swift 3**:

```
DispatchQueue.global(attributes: .qosBackground).async {
    print("This is run on the background queue")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to be into main thread to update UI, that's ok. But it means that there is a value that is nil somewhere. Try to find which one.

Comment: it says my `self.newestPublicationsCollectionView.reloadData()` is nil, while it isn't (shows data when app is open)

Comment: Is `newestPublicationsCollectionView` nil when it occurs?

Comment: You can not update UI  when application is in background mode. Save your data and do it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method. Because every UI control/IBOutlets will be nil in background mode.

Comment: @TheTiger Already tried that, and it still crashes, giving back that all views and buttons etc. are nil. Is it possible that it gives back nil because my PublicationOverviewController is in a tabbarview controller?

Comment: @SoundShock No! You haven't tried that. You are trying to reload your collection view forcefully in main thread while your application is in background. UI control probably will be nil.

Comment: @TheTiger I mean that I already tried the suggestion you gave before, and that also didn't work. (not in this code though, you are correct about that).

Comment: @SoundShock `NSLog` your data and `collectionView` in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method and see they would not be nil.

Comment: @TheTiger can you post an example as answer? I've tried the following     `func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            let fetchViewController = PublicationOverviewController()
            fetchViewController.updateCollections()
        }` but it still crashes, my Collectionviews are nil

Comment: @SoundShock Don't initialize `PublicationOverviewController()` again. Okay do one thing... Post a notification in `didBecomeActive:` method and observer it in `PublicationOverviewController` then reload your collectionView in respective method.

Comment: @TheTiger this actually worked without giving all the nil issues. If you put this as an answer, I can mark it. Thanks!

Comment: @SoundShock Sure.. Please mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't initialize `PublicationOverviewController()` again because it will give you new instance of that view and you would not get your referenced `collectionView`. Also you will get all UI controls nil before `viewDidLoad:` get calls.

Example:

```
let *controller : PublicationOverviewController = PublicationOverviewController()
// controller.collectionView will be nil here because view hasn't loaded yet
```

What you can do Post a notification in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method and `observe` it in `PublicationOverviewController` then reload your `collectionView` in respective method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give to you app 30 second timeout on background fetch, before starting UI operations, this can be helpful to your background network connection:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let fetchViewController = PublicationOverviewController()
                fetchViewController.fetch {
                    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
                    fetchViewController.updateCollections()
                    completionHandler(.NewData)
                }
}
```

You can also use this function:

```
func dispatchDelay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

call it as this example:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        let fetchViewController = PublicationOverviewController()
                    fetchViewController.fetch {
                        dispatchDelay(25) { // put what you want
                            // this is main-thread queue
                            fetchViewController.updateCollections()
                            completionHandler(.NewData)
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but now the crash just delays (but it still occurs).  I will give the full version of what is happening in my updateCollections() function, maybe that can help

Comment: Right, so now we have to exclude too fast attempts to main threads, now I check your update..

Comment: In my PublicationFetcher.shared.fetchAllPublications() I do the following (1. get data from backend, and 2. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RELOAD_NOTIFICATION", object: nil)
                }` and under that Reload notification I do a `updateCollections()`. Maybe it's a conflict between them?

Comment: Sure, you must remove it. Too many calls to updateCollections() and here in this comment you dont respect performFetchWithCompletionHandler delays

Comment: but is it still useful for me to actually still implement the `fetchViewController.updateCollections()`? Shouldn't doing the .fetch alone solve the problem? (not sure though)

Comment: I suppose updateCollections() work to your UI elements. So there are no problems if you launch it to the main queue.. look at the end of my function dispatchDelay (dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure))